# Safe or unpractical to use UTF-8 page names or other text? - User submitted text!

Tags: security, url, utf-8

I am working on a site that have an international aim; I.o.w., logged in users can add text in their own language. I am hoping for international page names and content.

An URL example, like the Japanese Wikipedia: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/メインページ (Both pagename and content text).

I know by using UTF-8, I can do this, but how should I control it?

UTF-8 contains way to many languages/letters to control in a script, I guess, so how safe/unsafe is it to allow people to add UTF-8 text?

I can see that someone could add harmful code this way, but how to prevent it?

All information regarding safety/control when using UTF-8 is appreciated!

EDIT: PS! I use PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: perhaps a slightly rusty response:

Note: not discussing host name (IDNS) issues.

The only completely safe thing here is to use %-escaped UTF-8. Some browsers will display this as what you want, and some will display the %-escapes. (e.g. http://foo.bar/%ee%cc%cf.html)

If you put 'real UTF-8' in the URLs, many things will work, but there may be unpleasant surprises lurking for some people in some browsers. I'm reading your question as dealing with 100% static content. If you are trying to do this with code behind the site, you have additional issues to work on.

The 'unpleasant surprises' would be (a) people finding the %xx's in the URL unreadable, (b) a browser that melts, (c) some data scraping or aggregating application that melts.

I wish I were more up to date on this, but I'm not, so my recommendation is to deploy a test site and then try to access it with everything you can put your hands on, including mobile phones. Persuade Google to index it, and see what happens there.

Comment: You mean that this "%_escapes" could happen, or are used in the Wikipedia example? Also, What unpleasant things, how to prevent it? Thanks!

Comment: URLs do not allow anything else but US-ASCII. That’s why the percent-encoding is used.

Comment: Except that some people routinely go right by this and put UTF-8 out there, ever since MS decided to support it.

Comment: So, unlike what Wikipedia does, good practice is to only stick to US-ASCII in any part of the url (including the page)? Meaning in reality for me: "a-z", "A-Z", "0-9", "+", "-" and "_"? But, doing this will of course limit the use for international users. On the other hand, it will make it very easy to control. I really don't want to create code that only certain browsers support (like IE), or "bend" any universal "standards" or recommendations.

Comment: @ErikH yes. But, take heart. if you use %xx to rep UTF-8, some people will be shown the real content some of the time.

Comment: bmargulies, But is this good practice? A link to this site (the one I'm working on) must work! If a large majrity of all web browsers will support UTF-8 in the URL this may be OK, but if not, the link will be broken (very bad). Could anyone please advise me to an objective good practice regarding using UTF-8 in URL's (page text, not domains)? Thank You!

Comment: @ErikH the recommended practice is to take UTF-8 and %-escape it.

Comment: bmargulies, Clear and "cut to the bone" advice". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For domain names, this is called [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). For page names, you may want to think of the possibility of [IDN spoofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).

Comment: Thanks, but IDN spoofs is not that big a problem for this site. It's possible harm to the site (server) its self, I'm worried about. The sites name would be http://www.mysite.com/User_Submitted_Name. An almost identical site (read page) name would not be a big problem because of the content (no personal info etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It's safe as long as you don't interpret it *literally* as SQL (SQL injection) or HTML (XSS) or any other language. Just escape any user-controlled input (request URL, request headers, request parameters, request body, etc..etc..) at the point it's going to be used in SQL or HTML.

It's unclear what server side programming language you're using, so I can't go further in detail.

Comment: Sorry to not mentioning this, but PHP and MySQL. Your answer have helped, and I am searching for info regarding this at the moment. Thanks! Yet, Even more info would be appreciated (no offense BulusC).

Comment: Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or parameterized queries while putting user-controlled input in a SQL query to avoid SQL injections. Use `htmlspecialchars()` while redisplaying user-controlled input to avoid XSS. This is by the way just the general approach, this is not related to using unicode per se.

Comment: Useful BalusC (sorry for misspelling your uname before), but unicode is my main problem. I have to be sure that I can control every single letter (UNF-8) entered into the database, and the output (the page). Manual acceptance is not possible because of the cost, so this has to be done in a script. Thanks!

Comment: To focus BalusC's suggestion, you should generally not have to escape any strings manually. Use libraries and conventions, like parameterized SQL queries, that take your user-provided input as arguments, and will process them safely.

Comment: Understand. Is there any potential known problems or security issues I should be aware of when doing this (not meaning basic programming code)? So, doing it "right" makes it 100% safe to use UTF-8 in the page text, controlling it and saving it in MySQL? Not the same as the URL, discussed in an another answer.